# DOORS DXL: How to create a folder

Tags: ibm-doors

I currently have some code that is supposed to create a folder if one with the appropriate name does not exist.  However, even though it gets to the code that tells me that the folder has been created, when I look for it, it isn't there.  The folder is supposed to be written to the desktop, but nothing new appears.  Here is the code I'm using:

```
if (!fileExists_(BL_TO_BL_DIR) {
    infoBox("Creating folder on desktop");
    Folder f = create( "C:\\Users\\" username() "\\Desktop\\BL_to_BL Files", "");
    infoBox("Folder created");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You confuse DOORS Folders with File System directories. 
In the DOORS client, you see DOORS projects, which have Folders(!), which contain Modules.

On your Computer, you have a file system with a directory. 
If you want to interact with your Operating System, like Windows, you will have to use the commands mentioned in chapter 12 of the DXL manual "Operating System interface". There you find the command `mkdir`.
Excerpt of the manual:

> Declaration
>
> void mkdir(string dirName [,string osParm])
>
> Operation
>
> Creates directory dirName.
>
> Optional argument osParm can contain information that is dependent on the operating system, such as the UNIX octal file access mask.
>
> Example
>
> The following example creates a typical UNIX path name, and sets the access rights:

`mkdir("/usr/development/phase1", "0755")`

> The following example creates a Windows path, for which there are no access rights:

`mkdir("C:\\DOORS\\DXLExample\\", "")`